# Ocamlfind: Package 'pprz.xlib' not found

Tags: package, ocaml

I am currently trying to install a set of ocaml packages. However, I cannot seem to find any site that allows me to download the 'pprz.xlib' package. The problem is that I would like to install that package for an ubuntu OS but I can't use the terminal to download it because I don't have internet access on the ubuntu. Therefore, I have to download it on windows, and copy and paste the package in the appropriate file in my project (it's the paparazzi code UAV for what it's worth).

Anyway, I would be greatly appreciative for anyone who may direct me to a solution on how to install such a package.

Thank you

Comment: I think that it is part of paparazzi. Their README mentions Ubuntu PPA  as source of their packages. You can try it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I've tried to install the packages, but nowhere do I see the package that I need (the one mentioned in the title of the question).